# AutoCompleteTextView NullPointer Exception

Tags: android

I have searched a long time and cannot find a solution to my problem. I am trying to create a Dialog with an AutoCompleteTextView. I followed the tutorial on the Android developer website, and it worked great. I have been successful using layouts on Dialogs before, so I thought this would be just as easy. I created a layout for my Dialog and I made sure that the AutoCompleteTextView has an ID. Here's where the interesting stuff happens...

```
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.auto_layout);       
 AutoCompleteTextView auto_tv = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.role_ac);
```

Here is the layout as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Role" />
    <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/role_ac" android:layout_width="280dip" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Done"
        android:id="@+id/auto_doneButton" />
</LinearLayout>
```

For some reason, auto_tv is null even though it does exist in the layout auto_layout. The only way I have been able to get an AutoCompleteTextView in a Dialog is by building the layout programmatically. Why is the AutoCompletTextView null when I try to use it? Did I forget something in my layout or am I not constructing the object correctly? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the context for where the line of Java fits into the app? What activity is it part of?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854336/autocompletetextview-backed-by-cursorloader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing two different contexts in your calls to `setContentView` and `findViewById`. In the first statement you're setting the content view of the object `dialog`.  In the second statement you're looking for an view in the parent activity. You want to make both calls using the dialog object. The correct syntax should be:

```
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.auto_layout);       
AutoCompleteTextView auto_tv = (AutoCompleteTextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.role_ac);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Just figured it out. Looked at too much code to catch my mistake. Here's the solution.

```
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.auto_layout);       
 AutoCompleteTextView auto_tv = (AutoCompleteTextView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.role_ac);
```

I needed to specify to use the Dialog's layout and not the main application's layout that was implied by not using `dialog.findViewByID.`